# Pandas - how to get mean of each level of many categorical columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
    cat1 cat2 res
0   a   d     3
1   a   e     2
2   b   d     7
3   b   f     6
4   c   e     4
5   c   f     5
```

How can I get the dataframe below (i.e., the mean of `res` for each level of `cat1` and `cat2`) using as little code as possible?

```
       res
cat1 a 1.5
     b 6.5
     c 4.5
cat2 d 5
     e 3
     f 5.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `melt` and `groupby`:

```
df.melt(id_vars='res').groupby(['variable', 'value']).mean()
```

Output:

```
                res
variable value     
cat1     a      2.5
         b      6.5
         c      4.5
cat2     d      5.0
         e      3.0
         f      5.5
```

Comment: Ah I forgot about `melt`. Thanks a lot Quang!